# Can my neighbors ham radio station be preventing my TV antenna from proper reception?

Tags: rfi, frequency, equipment

I have a winegard 8200 series antenna and it worked flawlessly in getting me reception of more than 70 stations. The wind blew it down and I couldn't replace it for about 6 months due to the fact that I couldn't get a suitable man lift into my yard because of the season and ground conditions. When I replaced it with a new one, my reception was seriously limited. I could receive signals in both the UHF and VHF ranges, however only a few in each. I have a rotor and tried every adjustment. I replaced the coaxial cable, my amplifier and the splitter card from winegard. Nothing worked. I was about to give up, when, out of the blue, my reception became flawless again! It only lasted a week and reverted to the limited reception that was unsatisfactory. I have discussed the issue with Winegard and they suggest that it is not an antenna issue. My neighbor is a Ham radio operator and his house is located between me and the broadcasting stations in the large metro area to the East of me approximately 60 miles away. I just learned that he is an amateur radio guy, because he has no large antenna on his property, which I thought was requisite for a Ham operator. My question is, can his equipment be somehow blocking my reception?

Comment: Welcome to Amateur Radio Stack Exchange! I believe that you will find relevant information and advice [in this existing well-answered question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/6887/can-my-neighbors-ham-radio-antenna-be-interfering-with-my-internet-signal-or-is?rq=1) — while that question is about internet service rather than TV, essentially the same considerations apply. If that does not tell you what you need to know, please [edit] your question to give more detail about how your situation is different.

Comment: Short answer: it's exceedingly unlikley that long term interfereance is from a ham; their interference would be intermittent and on the order of minutes long at most.  However, a lot of hams are good at fixing problems like this, so you should approach your neighbor with the attitude of "can you help me fix this, I know you might be an expert in this" rather than "are you causing this"?

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.  I was wondering, how does a ham communicate with the system if he doesn't have an antenna?  My neighbor has no visible exterior antenna and it has always been my experience that hams had a large antenna.  I'm told that it is no longer needed.  What's  the scoop?

Comment: For best results, post this as a question.  Short answer, not all antennas are big, some antennas can fit inside the house, some antennas are stealth and just not visible.  And not all hams actively transmit all the time.