# Will my neighbor's amateur RF antennas effect my own utilities?

Tags: rfi, united-kingdom, safety

I am buying a house in the UK and the property next door has two poles for antennas.

The next door lady seems to be very nice person and said her husband is an RF engineer and he used these on weekends. My basic question: will it effect any of my internet or TV or telephone?

I am planning to have fiber broad band.

[image: One tall antenna mast behind a house with smaller antennas on roof]

Comment: Welcome, Muhammad! I've edited your question a bit, hope you don't mind. You may also find https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/6887/can-my-neighbors-ham-radio-antenna-be-interfering-with-my-internet-signal-or-is to be helpful (and the way this site works your question may end up getting linked as a duplicate to that one too if people agree that the answers will be similar enough).

Answer (score 4):

The frequencies your neighbor would be transmitting are different than the ones your own communications would use. They should not interfere with your utilities.

Occasionally, funny things like old metal connections can end up re-broadcasting related frequencies instead of the original one, but this is usually accounted for as well when the allocations are made between TV/amateur/cellular/etc. bands.

It is encouraging that the neighbor not only appears to be a "ham" (trained and licensed hobby radio operator) but is also a professional RF engineer, so I doubly doubt you should have any problem. A big antenna like that would used for frequencies no where near the frequency of your WiFi. And it would be extremely unlikely for a wireless radio signal to interfere with an optical fiber internet connection itself.

Comment: Fibre is light, not coax, there is NO interference with the connection.

Comment: @RowanHawkins you're right, but: Marketing... I can actually order "Vodafone Fiber" on the internet and then get a contract signing me up for the internet-via-tv-coax-cable daughter...

Answer (score 2):

No, this will affect nothing. Otherwise, the neighbor would not have gotten the right to operate these antennas.